# Want to compare [.so] files in two apk's

Tags: java, android, shell, apk, .so

I want to compare the names (text) of .so files in two apk's

I write a batch script for pulling the app. Now , the app is at a desired location. How can i compare .so files.I am using java.util.zip for unzipping purpose and then trying to compare the directory structure.
My code is

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.Runtime;
public class batchrun {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
         String[] command = {"cmd.exe", "/C", "Start", "C:\\test1.bat"};
            Process p =  Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);           
}catch (IOException ex){}
    }

}
```

and my batch file is

```
@echo off
cd C:\app1
set /p UserInputPath= enter path
adb pull %UserInputPath%
```

I am clueless as in how to proceed from here

Comment: what do you mean with "but apk's dont fall under .zip category" ? apk's are just zips

Comment: .apk format is not supported in java .zip library as far as I can understand by reading over the net and similar is the case with .7zip and WinZip

Comment: have you tried it? I think this should work - otherwise you might give zip4j a chance

Comment: Okay....lets try that once. Thanks ligi :)